# When a Resource Event Occurs Logic App Triggered Twice

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-eventgrid

I've created a Logic App triggered when a resource event occurs, but it's triggered twice for each blob created.

Logic App details:
Trigger type: When a resource event occurs
Subscription: abc
Resource Type: Microsoft.Storage.StorageAccounts
Resource Name:  abcxyz
Event Type Item - 1: Microsoft.Storage.BlobCreated
Prefix Filter: /blobserv/default/subfold
Suffix Filter: .pdf

From what I can find online, an event is fired when writing to blob is initiated, and another event is fired when the writing has been completed. This would explain the Logic App being triggered twice.

I tried to update the Logic App to filter on blob size, but it appears to be the same value for both triggered runs.
Get Blob Metadata using path (v2):
Size: 41556

So, is there a way to know if the Logic App is firing off the creation or completion event or another way to filter out the creation trigger?

Comment: I tried to repro the same using the mentioned connectors but could see one trigger unless I upload the same file twice. Could you please help us understand whether your logic app is running twice or triggering twice? Also Can you please let us know the whole flow of your logic apps and the triggers that you are using in the logic app?

Here is the flow for your reference that I tried to repro
When a resource event Occurs -> Compose(to extract the file path) -> Get Blob Metadata using path.

Comment: It appears to be something on my side that is triggering the Logic App twice.  Once I figure it out, I will reply to this post in hopes that it helps someone else.

Comment: @Taco_Buffet: were you able to find out issue from you end ?

Comment: I'm now able to replicate the issue using a Power Automate Flow.  The Flow creates a new blob and the Logic App gets triggered twice.  @MadhurajVadde-MT

Comment: As I was not able to present the Operation tables in comment section, added response at ans section

Answer (score 1):

I might have narrowed down your issue.

1. Every `Put Blob Container` Operation triggers two events (`Started` and `Succeeded`)

   ```
   | Operation name | Status | 

   | Put blob Container | Succeeded |

   | Put blob Container | Started |
   ```
2. Adding filter at Logic app level

> Operation name == Put Blob Container
>
> and
>
> Status == Succeeded

should address your concern

Comment: i found a way to filter on Event Subscription.  I'm using Event Grid to look for new files being added to the blob container, so filtering on the Logic App is/was not an option unless I'm missing something.    thx for the reply!

Comment: @Taco_Buffet you solution would be helpful to other people you know ;)